# Wordpress MEga Menu Plugin Error On Plugin Page

Tags: wordpress

Plugin error showing at the top of the wordpress plugin page
after updating the plugin this error pop up
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9EHS.jpg
Iam using [WP MEGA MENU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkJVX.jpg)
How to remove this error
PS: PLUGIN IS WORKING PERFECT ON THE FRONTEND

[enter PLUGIN error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkJVX.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry because it's not related with something you did, it's just bug from Mega Menu plugin. They will fix it in the next release.
 More details here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/getting-the-plugin-url-in-the-plugins-section/